# img tag width height issue in firefox

Tags: html, css, image, cross-browser

I have more img tag in my HTML code like below code,

```
    <div id="container" >
    <div>
        <img alt="Image1" id="Image1" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="img">
         <input type="file" id="files1" class="fileUpload" name="files1[]" style="display:none" value="Select Image"> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <img alt="Image2" id="Image2" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="img">
         <input type="file" id="files2" class="fileUpload" name="files1[]" style="display:none" value="Select Image"> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <img alt="Image3" id="Image3" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="img">
         <input type="file" id="files3" class="fileUpload" name="files1[]" style="display:none" value="Select Image"> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <img alt="Image4" id="Image4" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="img">
         <input type="file" id="files4" class="fileUpload" name="files1[]" style="display:none" value="Select Image"> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <img alt="Image5" id="Image5" src="" width="130px" height="90px" class="img">
         <input type="file" id="files5" class="fileUpload" name="files1[]" style="display:none" value="Select Image"> 
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated :

MyCSSsoFar.css

```
#container {
  width: 600px;
}

#container div {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

when i run this on chrome its display with its width height like below image,

[image]

But when i run in firefox its not display with orginal width and height like below image,

[image]

I want to display with its width and height like chrome in all browser.How to fix this?

Comment: How does your CSS look like so far?

Comment: try with add ``<style>.img{display:inline-block;}</style>``

Comment: @pbaldauf check my question now.

Comment: @MrJerry Its working but no border in firefox like chrome.

Comment: try agian ``<style>.img{display:inline-block;border:1px solid;}</style>``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the `display: block` property on your `img`-elements. By default the browser would add `display: inline`.

```
img {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a quick [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egtsup9p/).

Answer (score 1):

Add following css:

```
.img{
    display:block;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

Check Fiddle here:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/jcvjLs2L/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Heres is a option if you want to show default broken image icon (this also fixes your problem)

```
img{
    -moz-force-broken-image-icon:1;
}
```